# What happens to resources held by abandoned generators?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a generator function which reads lines from a file and parses them to objects.  The files are far too large to consider processing the entire file into a list which is why I've used the generator and not a list.

I'm concerned because when calling the generator, my code will sometimes break. if it finds what it is looking for it can chose to stop before reading every object from the file.  I don't really understand what happens to the abandoned generator, or more importantly I don't know what happens to the open file handle.

I want to avoid resource leaks here.

---

Example code:

```
def read_massive_file(file_path)
    with open(file=file_path, mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as source_file:
        for line in source_file:
            yield parse_entry(line)

for entry in read_massive_file(my_file):
    if is_the_entry_i_need(entry):
        break
else:
    # not found
    pass
```

---

My question is: will the above code leave my source file open, or will python find a way to close it?

Does the fact I consume from a `for` loop change anything?  If I manually obtained an iterator for `read_massive_file()` and called `next()` a few times before abandoning the iterator, would I see the same result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This only releases resources promptly on CPython. To really be careful about resource release in this situation, you'd have to do something like

```
with contextlib.closing(read_massive_file(my_file)) as gen:
    for entry in gen:
        ...
```

but I've never seen anyone do it.

---

When a generator is discarded without fully exhausting it, the generator's `__del__` method will throw a `GeneratorExit` exception into the generator, to trigger `__exit__` methods and `finally` blocks. On CPython, this happens as soon as the loop breaks and the only reference to the generator is discarded, but on other implementations, like PyPy, it may only happen when a GC cycle runs, or not at all if the GC doesn't run before the end of the program.

The `GeneratorExit` will trigger file closure in your case. It's possible to accidentally catch the `GeneratorExit` and keep going, in which case proper cleanup may not trigger, but your code doesn't do that.

Answer (score 0):

You never save the return value of `read_massive_file`; the only reference is held internally by the code generated by the `for` loop. As soon as that loop completes, the generator should be garbage collected.

It would be different if you had written

```
foo = read_massive_file(my_file):
for entry in foo:
    ...
else:
    ...
```

Now you would have to wait until `foo` went out of scope (or called `del foo` explicitly) before the generator could be collected.

Comment: Yes, but does the garbage collector understand it has to close the file resource?

Comment: Yes; the `with` statement guarantees the file will be closed.

Comment: @chepner: Isn't it the finalizer in this case, not the `with`?

Comment: I'm not sure of the exact details, but the `with` statement guarantees that `file.__exit__` is called for the file object opened inside the generator. That should include the `with` statement terminating because the generator is being destroyed.